# PHP negatives keep adding

Tags: php, math, if-statement

I have this code here...

```
$remaining = 0;
foreach($clientArrayInvoice as $key=>$row){
            $remaining = $remaining + $row['total'];   
}
```

What it does, it takes the values of total and adds them up...but when I have values that are negatives, it adds them up as well for an example when I have `-51.75` and `-17.85` I get `-69.60` which it should be `-33.90` how do I fix this?

`-33.901 is the value I am expecting because when its two negatives I would like to subtract, not add

Thanks,
J

Comment: Your math is wrong. PHP is right. -51.75 plus -17.85 is -69.60.

Comment: Are you sure? That sounds like correct behaviour. Two negative values added create an even lower number.

Comment: -51.75 + -17.85 is -69.60 - why are you expecting -33.90? What are you expecting if you have 51.75 + 17.85? Or 51.75 + -17.85?

Comment: Also note that floating-point arithmetic is not exact. If this is money you are handling you should avoid floats entirely.

Comment: okay, I understand PHP is right, but when its a negative I would like to subtract instead of add

Comment: @user1269625 this is exactly what the `abs` function *does*...

Answer (score 10):

This might help:

```
(-51.75) + (-17.85) = -69.60
(-51.75) - (-17.85) = -33.90
```

Assuming you always need to *add* the second number regardless of it's sign, you need to take the absolute value by using [the PHP `abs` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) with `$row['total']`:

```
$remaining = 0;
foreach($clientArrayInvoice as $key=>$row){
    $remaining = $remaining + abs($row['total']);   
}
```

---

In response to what you updated in your question:

> -33.90 is the value I am expecting because when its two negatives I would like to subtract, not add

This is pretty much what using the `abs` function does.  I could rewrite the above code snippet as:

```
$remaining = 0;
foreach($clientArrayInvoice as $key=>$row) {
    if ($remaining >= 0) {
        $remaining = $remaining + abs($row['total']);   
    }
    else {
        $remaining = $remaining - abs($row['total']);   
    }
}
```

However, this does the exact same thing as simply using the PHP `abs` function, since you are always adding the magnitude of `$row['total']` to `$remaining`.

Answer (score 3):

again --> see php's [abs() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) if you want to add things and ignore the sign.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your question is exactly, but this would keep adding the absolute values if `$remaining` is negative until it is positive again.

> $remaining = $remaining + ($remaining < 0 && $row['remainingbalance']
>   < 0 ? -1 : 1) * $row['remainingbalance']);

This works for your example, it would be `0 - 51.75 + 17.85 = -33.9`. But I am not sure if it's the behavior you want in the bigger picture.