# PHP Math issue with negatives

Tags: php, math, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP negatives keep adding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145882/php-negatives-keep-adding)

I have this code here....

```
$remaining = 0;
foreach($array as $value=>$row){
        $remaining = $remaining + $row['remainingbalance'];
}
```

What its doing is that it is going through all the remaining balances in the array which are `-51.75` and `-17.85` with the code above I get `-69.60` which is correct. But I am wondering how when its two negatives if they could subtract? Is that possible?

I tried this

```
$remaining = 0;
foreach($clientArrayInvoice as $value=>$row){
        $remaining = $remaining + abs($row['remainingbalance']);
}
```

but it gives me `69.60` without the negative.

Anyone got any ideas?

my goal is to take `-51.75` and `-17.85` and come up with `-33.90` only when its a negative to do subtract. otherwise add

Comment: I don't really understand your question? What do you mean with ' But I am wondering how when its two negatives if they could subtract?'? Can you give an example?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking? You have an example that works, but you want to use `abs`, and then it doesn't work? What is your goal?

Comment: Updated my question with an example

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you add a negative number, you actually subtract the positive value (and the other way around).

So `0 + (-16) = 0 - 16 = -16`.

When you call `abs()` you calculate something completely different.